# PHP: Applying multiplication factor to a broad number of values

Tags: php, performance, audio, pack

I'm coding an audio amplifier in order to apply an envelop on an audio track. The audio comes from a file containing raw 44100 KHz 16-bit stereo samples. I coded something like below. In order to simplify the example, the amplification factor is constant but is varying in the real project.

```
<?php

$arrRawSamples = unpack('s*', fread($resAudio, 4096));
$fltAmpFactor = 0.8;

foreach (array_keys($arrSamples) as $intKey) {
    $arrRawSamples[$intKey] = $arrRawSamples[$intKey] * $fltAmpFactor;
}

$strAmpSamples = call_user_func_array('pack', array_merge(array('s*'), $arrRawSamples));

php>
```

This works well and I can play the audio after the multiplication factor is applied but the loop consumes a huge amount of CPU (about 2% CPU only unpacking/packing without the amplification loop, 25% with the loop). Could you please tell me if you know a less CPU consuming solution?

Comment: This is a typical case that should _not_ be implemented in PHP. This is not what a scripting language is there for.

Comment: Is `$arrSamples` a separate array defined elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah try using Gearman with PHP and another suitable language to do this process for you.

Comment: @TomFenech no, it's not defined elsewhere.

Comment: @arkascha I agree with you. I'm trying to figure out if a DSP can be coded with pure PHP code. I may try to code a C++ module for PHP in order to process these computations, but if I can to it another way...

Comment: @fruityp the aim is be able to run such a system on only one computer.

Comment: Ultimately `c` is the best suited language for this, unless you want to implement in assembler. `c` implementations of such computation tasks can be optimized to deliver a performance and efficiency that comes very close to assembler code. Plus you have fewer impacts from the hardware architecture (CPU) you have to deal with yourself. Maybe you want to implement a php extension. That indeed would make sense and a very welcome contribution.

Comment: You can run Gearman on the same computer for PHP to talk to another language, such as `c` mentioned by arkascha.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using array_map with anonymous functions. May be this can give you small performance boost.

```
array_map(function($a) { return $a * fltAmpFactor; }, $arrRawSamples);
```

But if the performance is essential in your application, really try to use more suitable language.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this, even if the real code is a little bit different, the amplification factor changes each 882 samples and the string containing the sample is much bigger. But this may be helpful, indeed.

Comment: I give it a try but comes up with 90% CPU usage against 25% with the loop above. :(

Comment: Why is a higher CPU usage worse? Isn't the speed of execution important to you as well? Your CPU "consumption" is usage * time.

Comment: It's worse as I may be able to process several signals in parallel. The CPU usage is limited as the code processing the audio signal is interrupted when the audio output buffer is full (time for the audio  to be reproduced by the soundcard). The final goal is to apply an envelope on the audio signals in order to chain them together and provide a continuous track list playback. For the moment, the code is only applying an envelope but will also have to mix tracks together. The more CPU available, the better, the signals are processed in real-time, the only limit is not have a buffer under-run.